# Handling Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, concurrency

I'm applying a rowVersion column to take care of concurrency issues. 
To test out these changes, I run my application and open up two different tabs. On the first tab I edit a field then on the second tab I edit the field. Then I save the changes in the first browser and I get the `DBUPdateConcurrency` exception. Even if I close out the other tab and just make the changes on the first browser it's still returning the `DBUPdateConcurrency` exception. Please see the code below:

**Class**

```
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set;}
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomerDetail model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int customerID = model.CustomerID;
        string comment = model.Comment;
        byte[] rowVersion = model.RowVersion;

        using (BusinessLogicLayer BLL = new BusinessLogicLayer())
        {
            try
            {
                Customer customer = 
                BLL.GetSingleCustomer(customerID);


                BLL.customerDB_entity.Entry(customer)
                    .OriginalValues["RowVersion"] = rowVersion;

                BLL.UpdateCustomer(customerID);

                BLL.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {

                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                var databaseEntry = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
                if (databaseEntry == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(
                        string.Empty, 
                        "Unable to save changes. The field was deleted by another user.");

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(
                        string.Empty, 
                        "Unable to save changes. The field was updated by another user.");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { customerID });
        }
    }
    return View(ViewModelManager.createEditViewModel(model.CustomerID));
}
```

Also, I added my hidden field for the row version in the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.RowVersion)
```

Comment: What is the value of `rowVersion` when the exception occurs? What is its value in the database?

Comment: What does your BusinessLogicLayer do? share the code of updating at _ BLL.UpdateCustomer(CustomerId) _

Comment: Thank you everyone! I figured it out! For some reason the rowVersion was returning null so I checked in the database and made an update to the rowVersion and now it's working.